# How to add computed values to a map inside a pipe?

Tags: elixir

i have this situation. I collect files from ftp servers.
for example a sample file

41199999
32355830
00003800
484E0040
48096E40
479E9B80
471B3F00
470A2100
431F0000
30305332
00003000
00003432
...

Each line in each file will be converted using a conversion formula
each line will be converted to key in a map. So i will have %{"ax"=>value} being x the number of the line and value the converted value.

Apart from that i need more keys,calculated keys, based on the keys already read from each file so in my code

i already get a map like this

```
%{"a1"=>1,"a2"=>2, etc}
```

at the line Enum.at(0) in the next code

```
|>Enum.map(&Tools.processFile(pid,&1,conversion))
|>Enum.at(0)
```

then my problem is how to add the calculated keys to the map.
I have for example the f1 function that takes a map and calculates the f1 key

```
def f1 map do
    %{"f1": map["a1"]+2}
end
```

How to add the f1 key to the map in the pipe code above so i will get

%{"a1"=>1,"a2"=>2, "f1"=>3}

Regards

Comment: What is the desired output? I know the input is `%{"a1"=>1,"a2"=>2, etc}` which format are you expecting as result?

Comment: %{"a1"=>1,"a2"=>2, "f1":3}

Comment: So you want to append to the existing map some new elements, which are computed from the elements in the existing map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this right, you should define your `f1` function such that it will append the value to the existing map, rather than returning just the new value. You can use `Map.put/3` for this:

```
def f1(map) do
  new_value = map["a1"] + 2
  Map.put(map, "f1", new_value)
end
```

Then you can just add that to the end of your pipeline:

```
# ...
|> Enum.map(&Tools.processFile(pid,&1,conversion))
|> Enum.at(0)
|> f1
```